# creating .cda file in Pentaho

Tags: sql, xml, pentaho

I am inside pentaho user console release 4.8.0.

1. How do I create a new .cda file? i.e. extract.cda
2. Which folder inside the server is this file located? (usual location information would be great :) )
3. I have a table called CustTable. I have 5 columns custId, userId, name, city and state.
   How can I create a new .cdi file where I can enter custID and userID and 4 columns pops up i.e. custId, userId, name and state.

e.g. if I enter custId=304, userId= 42 then result should be something like 
304, 42, Bryan, VA

I can write a SQL as: 
    select custID, userId, name, state from custTable where custId=304 and userID=42;

How can I accomplish it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Each time you create dashboard using CDE , you'll have cda file for your dashboard
2. It's located in folder where you save your dashboard file , usually : biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\xxx
3. Create datasource in your dashboard using CDE. Use this sql :

```
select * from custtable
where custID = ${custid}
and userID = ${userID}
```

Don't forget to create two paramaters (custID, userID) for this datasource

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed CDE?  It could be that you have not yet got this installed, which could be leading to the confusion. It is an extra plugin that comes with Pentaho. Install it from the marketplace, or for more flexibility use the installer script here:

https://github.com/pmalves/ctools-installer

Answer (score 0):

You need to install CDE to your pentaho BI and hope this link you understand more CDE dashboard http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxicLR0y8Vg